# Custom Javascript templates for third party tool

Tags: java, asp.net, webforms, javascript

We have an incident management tool, where sometimes we need to fill in repetitive data to close an incident(mostly a JSP or aspx page), I was just wondering is there any way to create a User defined Javascript Plugin: which can do following:

1. User defined and starts with broeser,
2. a check button , when clicked allows the JAVA code to acces Data a
   Text or Xls sheet
3. And finally polulate teh data into the repective cell in the webpage

Please give a brief outline of how to create and deploy this Javascript ,I have eclipse and Java installed in my system

PS. Our incident management tool is a secured website it is (https://itsm.******.com/arsys/forms/amrrm6100/SHR%3ALandingConsole/Default+Administrator+View/?cacheid=cfe755b8)

And it has multiple tabs under which the data has to be filled.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i understand you the right way but i think a browser plugin can help you.

have a closer look at grease monkey for firefox.

This one allows you to modify websites to your needs (maybe with a drop down box of default texts) without touching the application itself.

Comment: hey thank you for reply, but I want to build a Plugin by myself as our company will not allow any external vendor made Plugin, and that too for IE as we can only use that in our company